# Derivatives using R

Tags: r, math, statistics

I'm new to R and I'm trying to differentiate `y=x^-2` but I am not sure what the lines of code should be in R. `>g=D(X^-2)` is what I believe should be the first line, is this correct?

Comment: There are lots of examples in at the bottom of the help page `?D`, have you tried those? I would suggest running all the examples one line at a time, I think you will learn the answer to this question and much more.

Comment: Okay Thank You and where do I find those examples?

Comment: Open the help page by entering `?D` or `help("D")` in the concole (or view it online [at RDocumentation.org](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/deriv)), scroll down until you see the **Examples** section.